# Exploring Likelihood Representation in Conditional Probability: Seeking Insights for Estimating $P[Y=y \mid X=x]$ in a Temperature Control System

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, bayesian

Consider an information source which produces the signals 1 and 0 with unknown probabilities. The output of the source is denoted by the discrete variable *Y*. *Y*=1 implies that the temperature of a process has exceeded a predefined threshold, whereas *Y*=0 implies that the process is under control (i.e., the temperature is below the threshold). The temperature threshold is represented by $\theta$. Assuming the process temperature (represented by *X*) follows a continuous distribution, how could $f_{X \mid Y=y}(x)$ be estimated?

**My proposed procedure:**

Using Bayes' rule:

$\begin{equation*}f_{X \mid Y=y}(x)=\frac{P[Y=y|X=x] f_{X}(x)}{P[Y=y]}\end{equation*}$

Where:

$P[Y=y] = \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} {P[Y=y|X=x]}{f_X(x)}dx$

Moreover, for the likelihood, possible representations (that I am considering) might be:

$P[Y=1|X=x]=\begin{cases}(1-p)/2, & x\leq a\cr p, & a<x< b\cr (1-p)/2, & x\geq b\end{cases}$

or:

$P[Y=1|X=x]=\begin{cases} p, & x=\theta \cr 1-p, & otherwise\end{cases}$

where *a*, *b*, and *c* are positive constants and *p* represents a probability estimate. Furthermore, $a<\theta< b$

**Specific questions:**
I am new to probability theory, so I would appreciate any help with the following questions:

1. Do any of the proposed likelihood representations make sense from a probabilistic perspective?
2. If they are incorrect, what could be examples of alternative representations for $P[Y=y|X=x]$ in the context of the described situation?

Comment: $P[Y=1\mid X=x]$ does not need to sum (or integrate) over $x$ to $1$, but $P[Y=y\mid X=x]$ does need to sum  over $y$ to $1$